# Possible to create a kotlin js app gradle config without webpack/npm/yarn?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

Is it possible to create a gradle config that uses the kotlin multiplatform plugin to create a project with a kotlin js client (and ktor/jvm back end) that does required the webpack/npm/yarn gymnastics which I have little use for? Even if I remove the webpack element from the config the build still seems to fail because of the yarn lock problem. (Can be worked around of course, but it just seems for simple apps all this complexity ideally could be avoided.)

Solutions that don't use gradle at all - like just calling the compiler(s) and other tools directly in a script - would also be welcome!

Comment: You can try looking through the docs for the [Kotlin command line compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html) and [its Kotlin/JS options](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#kotlin-js-compiler-options). There's also an [npx compiler](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app)

Comment: Thx.

Actually, I tried the 1.8 kotlinc-js, but this seems to be linked with the old (non-IR) compiler and basically craps out. There doesn't seems to a compiler script for js/IR.

But to be the subject of separate question, I think